# Transaction not connected, or was disconnected error

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, bulkinsert

I am getting

> "Transaction not connected, or was disconnected error"

error when the transaction is either committed/rolled back after doing a bulk insert (along with some other operations).

```
using(var tran = Session.Session().BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
    {
       // do something
       fullSession.Session().CreateSQLQuery(query).ExecuteUpdate();// this query bulk insert in a temp db
       // do something else
       tran.Commit()/ tran.RollBack();// if transaction is active and not already rolled back/committed
    }
```

If the query to bulk insert from a file into a temp database fails, I get this error on tran.Commit/rollback.

Comment: The first exception has the message "could not execute native bulk manipulation query (followed by the query)". The exception thrown while rolling back the transaction (or committ) has got "Transaction not connected, or was disconnected error" only. However, the stack trace may be useful. The stack trace is "  at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.CheckNotZombied()
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Commit()"

Comment: @GyanendraSingh You refer to "the first exception" and "the exception thrown  while rolling back the transation". I'm dealing with a similar problem ("Tran not connected" being thrown from CheckNotZombified) but I don't have any other exception. Where did you get your "first exception" from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bulk Insert is a combination of Insert statements so if it fails it doesn't roll back the transaction so if you really want to catch the error try using Try and catch block inside BEGIN and END transaction

Comment: Actually, i do have a try catch block around the sql query execution. However, when it fails, i need to rollback the transaction(operations performed before the bulk insert). However, even rolling back the transaction does not work , and i get this "transaction not connected or was disconnected error".

Comment: When you are using Bulk Insert inside a transaction ,you can never roll back if it fails .Actually bulk Insert does not support rollback

Comment: Ok, but transaction commit should work if bulk insert fails. Why does that not work?

Comment: It will be helpful if you post ur sql query .

Comment: Based on your comment "when it fails, i need to rollback the transaction(operations performed before the bulk insert)." the simplest way of achieving this is to use the query "set xact_abort on" before u begin your transaction .It will automatically rollback the transaction if it raises an error .Please go thru the below link for detailed explanation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this exact same error using NHybernate while persisting an entity that had a property of type `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime?` (Nullable).

Changing the property to a regular `System.DateTime?` fixed the problem.

Comment: You fixed one of the reasons (and hence prevented this error from occuring) for this error to oocur. However, this question was more about such an error taking place, such that the transaction is closed. In the example from the question, the bulk insert from query in a temp table failed, closing the transaction.

Comment: Ok, but since this question comes on top of google when searching for that error, I figured this answer might be of some help for others. It is indeed not a direct answer for your specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problem, but it gone after I close connection in MS SQL Managment studio.

Comment: I did some research into this thing quite a while back, and wrote a post about the same. Not an ad, but you can take a look here http://nameless-programmer.blogspot.nl/2012/06/transaction-not-connected-or-was.html