# How to deal with procedure exec exception?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, nhibernate

I am calling procedure with param this way (by using NHibernate session):

```
var session = (NHibernate.ISession)GetConnection("BookDataBase");//NHibernate.ISession
var query = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec UpdateBook @BookId=:bookid");
query.SetInt32("bookid", bookId);
query.ExecuteUpdate();
```

This works fine except one thing. This part is called in handler, so there are situations when this part is called two times in a row (different changes but the same bookId), and ofcource, they can run simultaneously.

So, when this part are trying to run second time I am getting this exception:

> Transaction not connected, or was disconnected

I suppose that this is happening because when second change tries to execute procedure, first one already did it and closed transaction.

How can I prevent this? I need to be able to execute 2 procedures simultaneously.

Comment: seems to be a common enough issue - see if these help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341509/nhibernate-and-transactions-transaction-not-connected-or-was-disconnected   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839399/transaction-not-connected-or-was-disconnected-error    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878493/nhibernate-exception-transaction-not-connected-or-was-disconnected

Comment: Hm... will try it. Yep, it seems to be a common issue, but I am newbie speaking of calling procedures with NHibernate session

Comment: all 3 questions I linked deal with that issue with NHibernate.

Comment: What kind application is this called from? Can you share more code around what do you do with the `session` variable after this code is executed?

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @user1666620 - you should probably focus around this...

> There's a problem with your session-per-request pattern
>   implementation. ASP.NET is multi-threaded and the session is being
>   closed when a thread terminates instead of when the request ends.
>   There are many examples of how to manage session-per-request and
>   NHibernate has a built in NHibernate.Context.WebSessionContext but I
>   prefer to use a dependency injection framework such as Ninject.

[NHibernate exception: Transaction not connected, or was disconnected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878493/nhibernate-exception-transaction-not-connected-or-was-disconnected)

You need to make sure Nhibernate isn't killing a shared connection after the first query completes.

Comment: As you can see in my question, I assume that NHibernate does exactly this thing (kills a shared connection) but how to deal with it?

Comment: @OlegsJasjko have you read the links in the answer of the linked question? http://vault.lozanotek.com/archive/2009/02/17/Contextual_Sessions_with_NHibernate_ndash_Part_1.aspx